# Monitoring tool for remote borg repository

Tags: backup, monitoring, cron, hetzner, borg-backup

I am currently using Borg Backup which is connected to a remote repository hosted in Hetzner. Borg is being run daily via cron. While I place some log files to see if backup is working, I would like to ask if anybody know a good Borg UI-based monitoring tool?

Thank you

Comment: **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. - Conceptually:  I would also avoid adding a yet another  monitoring solution dedicated to a single solution/product/problem and  rather urge you to investigate how to integrate this  problem in your current existing monitoring. For example:  your monitoring should trigger an alert whenever your cron batch exits with an error, when the most recent (completed) backup is older 2 days, or when that status can't be determined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob.

Comment: Ok, I thought that my question would fall under the allowed ones (2nd bullet point): tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these